# My computer with AMD graphics shows gradients with consecutive rows of colors as a single color, instead of smoothly changing. How can I fix this?

Tags: ati, graphics, fglrx

Consider this image:

[image: a gradient]

I've examined the pixel contents of the image and every row of pixels (outside the white border) has an entirely different color value.

This would look right on my old laptop, with a nVidia Quadro FX 2700M. However, on this new laptop, with "AMD A6-6310 APU with AMD Radeon R4 Graphics", instead of having a smooth gradient, I see that chunks of rows all have a solid color, as if the granularity of the gradient has been reduced.

This seems to affect **all** gradients, regardless of whether they're in the GUI or in an image. In the image above, the banding seems to happen every 4 pixels. In my GNOME 3 titlebars, it seems to happen every 9 pixels. (It even happens with radial gradients!)

I can try to provide a photograph, if this still doesn't make sense.

This is Ubuntu GNOME 14.10 on a Lenovo G50-45. The screen appears to be (I'm not 100% sure) a SDC 4852. I am using fglrx (`fglrx-updates` from the repository); I forget if mesa (installed by default; had freezing issues) had the same issues. `xwininfo -root` says my screen bit depth is 24-bit; I don't see any distortion of what colors I can see, so... I use GNOME 3's screen magnification, but that doesn't seem to affect anything because I can still see the banded titlebars when fully zoomed out.

Is there anything I can do to get smooth gradients back? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears to be the result of the laptop's screen being of dubious quality, not a software issue :( I've switched to a MacBook Pro (mid-2012) and its screen does not seem to have these issues (from what I can tell). (Someone on Freenode whose nickname I do not have on me right now brought up the possibility a while ago.)

Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Which driver are you using? The ATI one from the ubuntu repo, the ATI one from the website, or the open source radeon driver?

Comment: `fglrx-updates` from the repos. Forgot to disambiguate that; sorry (edited question).

Comment: Good, that driver also installs AMD Catalyst Center, found in your app menu. You launch it and play with the settings. I have a hunch that in the name of performance/power savings, the quality is dropped. There is also a "shutter free" bug which affects gradient rendering ( menu option in the Cat Center). The best part is that when you hit apply, the settings do get applied. No need to log off or restart. Try and see what works for you.

Comment: Hm; I tried playing around with some power settings but they didn't seem to have an immediate effect, and neither did the few other settings I could change. I could try logging out and seeing if that helps, but at a later time. What's the info on this other bug? Thanks in the meantime!

Comment: Try display options-> TearFree ( that's the bug) and try in 3D -> More Settings to slide towards quality and set the AI to advanced. Ultimately, try disabling the AI, with the slide on quality.

Comment: Another thing, since this is an APU, it's worth installing apt-get install microcode.ctl and amd64-microcode . That will pull the latest and greatest in flight APU patch from AMD. It might fix the issue.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. None of it worked. Even better: I just upgraded to Vivid and switched back to Mesa; it definitely *does* happen there too! I'll wait for Vivid to go final before I update this question.

Comment: btw, for vivid install linux-firmware-nonfree as well. They usually have new firmware/bios for various components. It might be that there's a newer one for your video card as well. Also if you can upgrade your bios as well. AMD upgraded their AGESA code a couple months ago.

Comment: Those didn't help at all. In fact, I'm starting to think it's the screen, not the video card... I would need to test an external display more closely, though. Thanks in the meantime, @user283885!

Comment: Has this been resolved? I really need an update, as I'm having the same issue. (Lenovo G50-45 with the same specs as you)

Answer (score 0):

I have a Lenovo-z50-75 and experience this same issue. Whilst I haven't resolved it, in the AMD Catalyst Center if you change the temperature to 'Use Display's Settings' (Under Color tab), this certainly reduced the issue for me.